# How to control voltage and current output for flyback converter with varying load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I managed to design a working flyback converter with a feedback. I have one last obstacle and I hope a kind soul is able to help me out. 
I placed a dummy load, for instance, I dictate it as 1 ohm. The waveforms are as attached.

Output 1: 12V, 12A
Output 2: 5V, 5A

1. Apart from connecting an additional resistor, how do I reduce the current for output 1 from 12A to 9A?
2. Is there a way to maintain the values as the load increases. I observed that an increase in load reduces the current.
   How would I do an additional current control feedback. A hint would be great for me to get started

   Below are some info that could be of help,

Np1: 100, Np2: 20, Ns1: 28, Ns2: 12, Lm: 788 micro F, Vs = 230V, Freq = 50hz, Switching Freq = approx 100Khz, Vref @ TL431: 2.5v
Dmax: 0.33,

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: Current Waveform]

[image: Voltage Waveform]

Comment: What do you mean with "increase in load reduces the current". Increase the load as in increase the resistance of the load?

Comment: You use feedback to make 12 V at the output, you connect a 1 ohm load, 12 A flows. All is well. Now you want 9 A to flow. Just make the load 12V/9A = 1.33 Ohm. Or keep the 1 ohm but lower the 12 V to 9 V (change R2/R3). Not sure what else you could mean.

Comment: @ Winny, @ FakeMostache, my apologies I think the question I should be asking would be , how do I maintain ideally 100 watts at output 1 ( for now it's 144) and 25 watts at output 2 irregardless of the size of the load connected

Comment: You need to measure both output voltage and output current, multiply those, compare their product (power) with your reference value (100W) and use that error signal in your NFB loop. Simplest circuit will involve analog multiplier, most practical nowadays may be an MCU.

Comment: Don't put space between @ and username or the person will not be notified. What is your goal? A constant power output within some boundary? A constant voltage-constant current output characteristic?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, may i enquire what is an NFB Loop? I decided to go with suggestion above and change the resistance value.

Comment: @winny , alright thanks for the heads up. My goal would be to generate a constant 100W at output1 and constant 25W at output2. Hence from my understanding correct me if Im wrong, both voltages and current have to be perfectly constant.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase, forget about specifying powers, just tell us what the load is and how much you can tolerate the voltage changing on the load. Specifying output power is, I think, a little strange unless you mean max output power.

Comment: That's mighty strange. If you keep the voltage constant, your current will vary according to the load. What is the end goal? Why do you need a constant 100 W output? What if the load is disconnected?

Comment: @andyaka , hi there. To be frank , I met with the prof the other day, he finalised what he wants , output 1 was to specifically supply 100 watts to the video portion of a television and 25 watts to the audio portion of the television , I believe getting the exact load value would only be by dismantling a tele and he told me to get it. At any point of time , max output power would be 100 watts and 25 watts, let's just say a tolerance of 10%

Comment: @winny I find that strange too, profs can be so weird at times, unless he's pulling a fast one one me. I've been at this project for 6 months, the goal is to supply the video and audio portion of a television

Comment: That's far away from a constant output power requirement! Your TV is for sure constant voltage on the rails!

Comment: @winny I believe I've screw up somewhere and I was sure the prof mentioned that, moving on, are you able to assist me or give me leads to where do I go on from my current circuitry ?

Comment: Use it as is? Measure/characterisize the cross-regulation between the rails? Wind the transformer better for lower leakage inductance? Shrink the footprint? The work never ends for an engineer :-)

Comment: what is an NFB Loop? Negative Feedback

Comment: Typical engineering talk -- "I want a 100W power supply", that almost always means "I want a power supply that can provide up to 100W", almost never means "I want a power supply at a constant 100W output" .